# What's the use-case of the Video Snapshot function on Canon cameras?

Tags: video, dslr, canon, short

While browsing the video settings on my Canon 77D, I came across a [peculiar function](http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/8200786000.html):

> What is the Video Snapshot function?
>
> The Video Snapshot function enables you to shoot short scenes that last for several seconds. The shooting time can be selected from 2, 4, and 8 seconds.
> You can enjoy viewing movies as you play back Video Snapshot scenes along with music. Also, by changing the music, you can give your scenes an entirely new feel when you play back.

There is also a similar feature on Panasonic cameras:

> Snap Movie
>
> Users can record video in a designated short period of time (2/4/6/8 sec) as they shoot “moving photos”. In this function, rack focusing or addition of a fade effect (color in/out, black in/out, white in/out) are available.

I can understand why someone would want to create a video slideshow with music on their camera, but why are those clips limited by Canon to 2, 4 or 8 seconds? Is this a particular genre that I'm not aware of or perhaps some sort of an Instagram-like website only allows videos in this format?

Comment: This is speculation,  so in a comment rather than an answer.  There is limited capacity for the on board android apps to work with, so the features characteristics are a compromise between what the designer wanted,  and what was possible. . The built in functions need to be manageable on a bare bones interface and limited resources.  They cannot replace a full editing suite , and should not be expected to.